# Getting wrong output from c program

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. I have written a program and I am getting the output `0 1` when 'a' is entered through the keyboard. From what I know about the `for` loop, it should not execute the statements of the body if the condition becomes `false`. So the output should be `0` when 'a' is entered.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{   int c;

    long nc=0;
    for(nc=0;c=getchar()!=EOF;++nc)
    {
        printf("%ld \n",nc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You entered `a` then `<return>`, so 2 chars are available for input, `0` is written for the first and `1`for the second. Everything correct.

--EXPLANATION REQUESTED BY OP--

start with `nc` equals to 0, first call to `getchar()` reads `a`, `nc` equals to 0 then `0` is printed, `nc` incremented so now equals to 1; then second call to `getchar()` reads `newline`, `nc`equals to 1 then `1` is printed, `nc` incremented so now equals to 2.

Comment: thanks for  you  reply , sir please explain working of program inside for loop